# Can ConcurrentLinkedDeque have a fixed size and overwrite old elements?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

If I got this right ConcurrentLinkedDeque acts as a stack right if you use `pollLast()` ?

Now my issue is that I need a set size of ConcurrentLinkedDeque. My producer doesn't stop, so even if I have 16GB of ram I will run out eventually. SO is it possible to se a fixed size ?

My implementation:

```
ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
```

Producer (Thread 1): runs `queue.add(line);`
Consumer (Thread 2): runs `queue.pollLast();`

Please note that **both** threads run in a **while true loop**. This is because of the requirements. That is why I am using `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` and not `ArrayBlockingQueue` or `SynchronousQueue` because it is non-blocking.

Also do I need to declare anything `synchronised` ?

Comment: Use a fixed size `BlockingQueue` which would allow you to apply back pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` have a fixed size?

No, it's *"an **unbounded** concurrent `Deque` based on linked nodes."*

> Do I need to declare anything `synchronised`?

`ConcurrentLinkedDeque` itself is thread-safe. Synchronisation is required only for composite actions (like overwriting old elements).

> Can `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` overwrite old elements?

I don't think there is such a method. That's a composite action that requires

- remembering the position of an element you are going to change and all the elements that come before/after;
- changing the element;
- restoring the order (putting the elements back).

These three actions should be performed within a `synchronized` block.

Comment: @TrtTrt, does the producer know the size you want to limit the collection to?

Comment: @TrtTrt, you could estimate the size of the collection before putting a new element in

Comment: @TrtTrt, if there's no room for a new item, you can wait (make the producer wait) until the consumer takes an element (frees some space) and notifies the producer

Comment: @TrtTrt, that's [the classical producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer–consumer_problem) - I should have mentioned it earlier